# Providing a Java Programm as (D)COM Service

Tags: java, com

I am looking for a solution (best example code) how to implement an register a Java Program as (D)COM Server/Service. More concise I have the following issue:

Initially situation is:

- (a) I have a Java Webservice (Axis) pulling in Data from the Web.
- (b) I have a 3rd Party service (written in Delphi) which wants the
  data from a COM-Object and is periodically calling this (the
  interface, which methods of the COM Object are called, is specified).

In order to get the data from (a) to (b), I need to implement a COM-Server which provids the needed methods for (b) to retrieve its data.

The main Question I have is:

**How can I make and register the Java Service as a COM-Object and provide the needed methods so that (b) get its data when calling.**

I know Java, but I am no expert to (D)COM. So, forgive me possible technical error concerning COM.
Searching the Web I found several tools/frameworks (e.g. JInterop) that allow a Java Program to interact with a COM-Object, but I did not found code etc. how to make a Java Program accessible via (D)COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look on [using Java Servers and DCOM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162164). An example is [idl server](http://gsraj.tripod.com/com/idlserver.html). Also, you can see [services tutorial](http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/entirex/exx71160/webservi/services.htm).